# Using SVG symbols in Firefox with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, firefox, svg

I'm trying to use SVG icons with Angularjs with `html5Mode` set to true.  In order to use `html5mode` urls, you need to set the `basePath` in the head of the html document.

```
<base href="/">
```

I then load all of my svg icons into the index.html page as symbols.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display:none">
    <symbol id="user" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <path d="...">
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

I can't figure out how to get this to work consistently in Firefox.  In Chrome and IE, I can always just set the svg `use` href to the id of the svg symbol.

```
<svg ng-class="type" class="main-nav-icon">
   <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#user"></use>
</svg>
```

However, none of the icons are displayed in Firefox. From a previous question, I was told that this was because of the `base` tag.  So I tried setting the `base` tag to an absolute url

```
<base href="http://localhost:5080/">
```

And then tried every combination of urls for the `use` tag. I finally got it to work if I use an absolute url based on the original path that the index.html page was downloaded from.

For example, if the page was loaded from `http://localhost:5080/user` then setting up the `use` tag like the following will display the icons:

```
<svg ng-class="type" class="main-nav-icon">
   <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://localhost:5080/user#user"></use>
</svg>
```

This works okay when the user is clicking around the app. However, if the user then refreshes the page on `http://localhost:5080/photos` all of the icons are broken again because the `href` is now incorrect. So then I started caching the original url that the index.html page was loaded from and using that. However, even then refreshing on some pages breaks all of the icons again.

Using `html5mode` with AngularJS, what is the right thing to set the `base` tag to and what is the right thing to set the `use` tag href to in order to make the icons show up in IE, Chrome, and Firefox?

Comment: Did you try setting the base href dynamically via JavaScript by location.href ?

Comment: That would break the AngularJS routing wouldn't it?

Comment: Have you seen this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742805/angular-and-svg-filters

Comment: No, I missed that one. Now I have icons being displayed, but the icons break if they are ever hidden and then shown again. To fix that I had to watch for `$routeChangeSuccess` and update the `<use>` href tags on every icon on every change which can't be good.

Comment: Nevermind, technique in my last comment sometimes breaks on Chrome when updating the URL. Icons just randomly go missing.

Comment: Just to throw it out there - instead of inlining SVG, you could create an [icon font](https://icomoon.io/) and use that.

Comment: @Bill I am struggling with the same issue. Tried using the approach to set requireBase as false.  Say the path was localhost/path1 which works fine everytime however, if the path is localhost/path1/path2 the relative path becomes localhost/path1 and thus all script loading or other links fail.  Did you face a similar scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like this bug that mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8934)
and fixed by Jeff Cross (from google) by [this](https://github.com/jeffbcross/angular-svg-base)

Auto directives to automatically rewrite absolute hash URLs for fragment references in SVG elements, to work around  side effects in Gecko and Blink.

Comment: Based on that bug, this did it for me: `$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});`. I can then remove the `base` tag and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody interested in an Angular 2 solution for this same issue, I was unable to find one, so I published this small directive to NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-inline-href