# <base> tag breaks SVG marker-end rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, d3.js

The goal is pretty simple: I want a curved red line with an arrow at the end.
[This JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yibar/5) is basically just that.

Now, to avoid a long story, let's just say I spent days figuring out why, in my environment, the browser only showed *just* the curved line. The a-ha moment was when I pasted into the JSBin some extra lines of `<head>` found on my page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<base href="/">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Boom! The arrowhead immediately disappeared. It happened in both Chrome and Safari. I celebrated the discovery, but I still don't understand how some middling lines of `<meta>` broke marker-end rendering. It must be intentional if it's a cross-browser event, but I just don't see how.

*Clarification:* It appears to be the `<base>` tag causing the fuss. It's an Angular project so I need it. How can I work around it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular and SVG filters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742805/angular-and-svg-filters)

Comment: Well darn, that slipped by me. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fully resolve the marker url.

If it is an arbitrary document which is using a `base` tag, then you can use `document.URL`.  For example, `"url(" + document.URL + "#end" + ")"` in place of `url(#end)` (line 167 of your example JSBin).

For angular in particular, there are two possible solutions.

First, if you are the marker-reference on the client (for example, using d3), then you need to fully resolve the URL yourself as above.

Second, if you are using server-side generated SVG you can use the angular scope.

`$scope.baseUrl = $location.absUrl();`

When you create the SVG, refer to the property.

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <marker id="end">...</marker>
    </defs>
    <line marker-end="url({{baseUrl}}#end)" .../>
</svg>
```