# How do I get the absolute path of the current page in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I've essentially run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19742805) problem, where I need a reference to the current route to use gradients, but have yet to figure out how to translate the solution into Angular 2.

Comment: There are various approaches proposed in the answers to this question. If you want to see them compared, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60705771/245602).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```ts
constructor(location:Location) {
  console.log(location.prepareExternalUrl(location.path()));
}
```

https://angular.io/api/common/Location#prepareexternalurl

As the documentation says:

> Normalizes an external URL path. If the given URL doesn't begin with
>   a leading slash ('/'), adds one before normalizing. Adds a hash if
>   HashLocationStrategy is in use, or the APP_BASE_HREF if the
>   PathLocationStrategy is in use.

It means that you have to explicitly specify APP_BASE_HREF to get an absolute path in Angular 5+.

`window.location` provides more information

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xvwySO0pwRXUn9CUXcJu?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering! I'm using the new router library in rc0 which doesn't seem to have a Location provider. Using `window.location.pathname` does seem to work fine for my purposes though, maybe I was just overthinking it a bit.

Comment: Ah, thanks again, I'd forgotten about `@angular/common`, I had only checked router and core.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This is only displaying after the base address! any updates?

Comment: Yup, I wasn't able to find anything that provides more info except `window.location` (see Plunker).

Comment: this does not work with angular 5 it gave me just the path

Comment: A couple of updates:
1) The actual documentation link is https://angular.io/api/common/Location#prepareexternalurl
2)  As the documentation says: "Normalizes an external URL path. If the given URL doesn't begin with a leading slash ('/'), adds one before normalizing. Adds a hash if HashLocationStrategy is in use, or the APP_BASE_HREF if the PathLocationStrategy is in use.". It means that you have to explicitly specify  APP_BASE_HREF to make it works. Tested in Angular 8.1.

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `DOCUMENT` injection from `@angular/common`.

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Component({...})
class SomeComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: any) {
    console.log(document.location.href);
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the only working solution I could find for Angular 5+

Comment: DOCUMENT is deprecated in angular 5+

Comment: @SatishPokala it's not in v8, v9

Answer (score 21):

### Location object

#### The document.location object is your one stop solution.

Use the attributes inside location object from document to get the path in the way you need. Let's see this with an example.

So for **`https://www.google.com/images`**

- **`document.location.href`** will return **`https://www.google.com/images`**
- **`document.location.origin`** will return **`https://www.google.com`**
- **`document.location.protocol`** will return **`https:`**
- **`document.location.host`** will return **`google.com`**
- **`document.location.hostname`** will return **`google`**
- **`document.location.pathname`** will return **`/images`**

Comment: the document object is a free object which you can access without any initialization.

Answer (score 2):

if you reload page , you can not get route path by Router or ActivatedRoute .
You should use `window.location.pathname`

Answer (score -1):

With base href:

```js
import { DOCUMENT, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';


@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: any,
    private readonly locationStrategy: LocationStrategy) {}

  // for localhost: http://localhost:4200/someBaseHref
  getUrl(): string {
    return `${this.document.location.origin}/${this.locationStrategy.getBaseHref()}`
  }

}
```