# How to get the current url in the browser in Angular 2 using TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I need to get the current URL present in the browser in my Angular 2 application.

In JavaScript normally we do it using the window object.

How can I do this in Angular 2 using TypeScript?

Thanks.

Comment: The same will should work for you

Comment: @KaushikThanki Thanks !! It works. Dumb question I guess :P Should have just tried ..

Answer (score 42):

This is late but I thought it was worth updating. As of Angular2 final release you can import DOCUMENT from @angular/common and use that to get to the location.

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

...

export class YourComponent {

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) { 
        console.log(this.document.location.href);
    }
}
```

Comment: `export 'DOCUMENT' was not found in '@angular/common'` as of `4.1.3`.

Comment: @Deilan I had a quick check of the source, it's still there https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/dom_tokens.ts

Comment: the problem with DOCUMENT approach is that you can't properly mock it in your tests

Comment: Just inject the mock in your test.

Answer (score 33):

It is not necessary to import complicated packages or inject something. Just use the methods you can find on `window.location`!

Such as:

- `window.location.href` gives you the full URL
- `window.location.hostname` gives you the host name
- `window.location.origin`with this command you get the host name with protocol (e.g. https://)
- and more as you can see here: [click me](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

> For IE<=10 users: location.origin may not be available, then you have to use `location.protocol + "//" + location.hostname` or use a polyfill or package like [`location-origin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-origin)

Comment: Please note it isn't recommended to use window directly with Angular as it not available on the server side when pre-rendering so will break Angular Universal (important if you are planning on having an SEO friendly site).

Comment: const url = new URL('../cats', 'http://www.example.com/dogs');
console.log(url.hostname); // "www.example.com"
console.log(url.pathname); // "/cats"

Answer (score 6):

You can

- inject `Location` and get the URL by `location.path()` (see also [Location and HashLocationStrategy stopped working in beta.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16/36861629#36861629))
- get it from the browser directly using `window.location.pathname`

See also

[How do I get the absolute path of the current page in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517183/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-path-of-the-current-page-in-angular-2/37517504#37517504)

Comment: Thanks..It works!! However when I tried using location.path() it shows nothing... Anyways its working if I directly use the window object.. Thanks again :)

Comment: Did you inject `constructor(location:Location){ console.log(location.path(); }`?

Comment: yes.
    `constructor(location: Location) 
    {
    alert(location.prepareExternalUrl(location.path());
    console.log(location.path());
    }`

Answer (score 5):

Import the ActivatedRoute, (and the rest of the Router stuff too, if you want)

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router, UrlSegment } from '@angular/router';
```

making sure it's injected into the constructor,

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { ... }
```

and on ngOnInit you can use `this.route` to inspect the URL. For instance, all the segments are in an array, which you can string together, as @ibgib suggested,  like this:

```
let path = this.route.snapshot.url.join('/');
```

to give you something like "mars/moons/phobos".

Comment: I personally like this version. However, `this.route.url` is an `Observable<UrlSegment>`. Perhaps instead of using a `forEach` to enumerate the observable which may produce multiple iterations, just use `this.route.snapshot.url.join('/')` instead?

Comment: Thanks @ibgib - used your code in the answer. Much more idiomatic.

Comment: Hmm I am getting empty path when using this method even though my url is not the root.

Answer (score 4):

For future travelers, a lot of the other answers are great. Another option, if you want everything before the pathname (e.g. `https://example.com`) then you can use:

`window.location.origin`

Here's a W3 article on the different `window.location` properties you can use:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Cheers!

Comment: this does not work. Errors out with: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: @Neurothustra You may try opening a new question and posting your code. I'm guessing it's race condition of some kind. Window is baked into the browser itself, so I'm guessing it's a local issue.

Answer (score 4):

This [Link](https://blog.josequinto.com/2017/03/09/typescript-functions-to-get-current-domain-site-collection-and-site-urls-with-window-location-fallback/#Introduction) helped me:

```
  public static getCurrentAbsoluteSiteUrl(): string {
    if (window
        && "location" in window
        && "protocol" in window.location
        && "pathname" in window.location
        && "host" in window.location) {
      return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has many options and always use easy coding rather complicating it. As it says keep it simpler. Here is the code below

```
const url = new URL('../cats', 'http://www.example.com/dogs');
console.log(url.hostname); // "www.example.com"
console.log(url.pathname); // "/cats"
```

As @[JayChase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3534636/jaychase) mentioned,

The Angular Universal will have issues while rendering and the whole application will fail due this window functions. Avoid using window functions.