# Idenfity www.* or m.*

Tags: google-app-engine, angular, mobile, responsive-design

I'm building a web app with GAE Python and Angular2. 
And one of the requirements is that the UI will be totally different between web and mobile. Like www.product.com and m.mobile.com.

How is the best way to identify, in Angular2 when the agent is mobile?

Comment: In "totally different" do you mean two different applications or one application where different styling is applied depending on `m.` or `www.`?

Comment: In the 2nd case see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796449/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-the-browser-in-angular-2-using-typescript/37796509#37796509

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, different styling and different components