# Angular4 get a routes full Url

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to get the full URL for a route, but nothing seems to be working and I can't find any documentation to do this.

I found this similar issue: [Get current url in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45184969/get-current-url-in-angular-4)

I have tried using `this._router.url` but it only gives the path. I need the entire Url, include scheme, etc.

Does anyone know how I can get the full URL for a route?

Comment: You'll have to use the document object. I've found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796449/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-the-browser-in-angular-2-using-typescript)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this

import section

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
```

constructor section

```
constructor(private _location: Location) {
 console.log(this._location.path()); //will give you current url
}
```

Comment: I'm don't understand why this is the accepted answer. The OP wants the full url, including the scheme. This returns just what router.url returns, just the path and nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by Ankur Garg works, since location.path() returns the path in the address bar and not the currently visible component route.

This is especially helpful in situations where the user has typed the url in the address bar and pressed enter.

For example if you type in https://somedomain.com/sent, this request will go to the server first and will not be handled by the angular route handling. In case of a catch all scenario common on Single Page Applications (SPA), where irrespective of the requested URL, always index.html is sent back by the server, the first thing that loads, would be app.component, and inside that, if you use router.url you will always get "/" and not "/sent".

So if you need to store the path that was originally requested by the user, you can use location.path() and keep it somewhere. Once everything is done on the client side, such as Authentication, Access verification etc, you can always redirect the user to the originally requested path.

This not only works with typed urls in the address bar but urls shared over emails, social media etc.