# Get full Url when using Angular2

Tags: angular

I would have thought finding this information would be simple with all the work that has gone into Angular2 but apparently not...

1) How can I get the **full** url of the activated route in Angular2? I know I can call `window.location.href` but was wondering if there was an Angular way.

2) Is there a way to "build out" a url? If I know when route I want and the parameters for said route, can I construct the **full** url?

Comment: The Plunker in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517183/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-path-of-the-current-page-in-angular-2/37517504#37517504 provides my attempts.

Comment: When the plunker snippet runs, you see "loading..." and then nothing. However, before I posted my question I saw your response during my searching but when I tried location.prepareExternalUrl(location.path()) I was only given back an absolute path...not the *full* path (full path should include protocol, host, port, etc.)

Comment: Open the browser console. There you get the output for all examples. Worked for me 2h ago.

Comment: The output being shown is `/xvwySO0pwRXUn9CUXcJu?p=preview`. As I already stated, `location.prepareExternalUrl(location.path())` is **not** showing the **full** url. For the full url, I would expect the ouput from your plunker example to be `https://plnkr.co/edit/xvwySO0pwRXUn9CUXcJu?p=preview`

Comment: This question was not well written. My intent was more complex then what was stated. My apologies. I would vote myself down but it seems you cannot do that on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build the url and wanna navigate you can use `navigateByUrl` method

```
router.navigateByUrl("/team/33/user/11");
// Navigate without updating the URL
router.navigateByUrl("/team/33/user/11", { skipLocationChange: true});
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigateByUrl-anchor

Comment: Sorry for delayed response Sumant -- I should have been clearer in that I did not want to do string concatenation. My question was more around "Is there a method I can call with parameters that will build out the url". That being said, I will give you credit since you answered the question as written.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full URL in Angular 2 with the help of [`document.location`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html).
It refers to the current URL. Additionally, `document.location` is equivalent to `window.location.href`.