# SVG not showing up when using <use>

Tags: svg, angular

I have trying to use svgs with the `xlink:href` property and it does not show up. If I try it on a completely fresh project, it works fine. I've also tried it on a fresh angular2 webpack project to see if it was related to angular2 but it worked perfectly there as well.

I have this included in the top of my component (I've also tried to place it in the `index.html` file).

```
<svg style="display:none">
    <symbol id="Icon-Gplus" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
        <title>Gplus icon</title>
        <path d="M80.6 111.8v27.6h45.7c-1.8 11.9-13.8 34.8-45.7 34.8-27.5 0-50-22.8-50-50.9s22.5-50.9 50-50.9c15.7 0 26.1 6.7 32.1 12.4l21.9-21.1c-14.1-13.1-32.3-21.1-54-21.1C36.1 42.6 0 78.7 0 123.3s36.1 80.6 80.6 80.6c46.5 0 77.4-32.7 77.4-78.8 0-5.3-.6-9.3-1.3-13.4H80.6v.1zM253.4 111.8h-23v-23h-23v23h-23v23h23v23h23v-23h23"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

If I try this, no svg shows up. It is worth noting that the box for it appears to be there, but no amount of fill change can get it to be visible.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 256">
     <use xlink:href="#Icon-Gplus"></use>                
</svg>
```

If I do this, it works great.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 256 256">
     <path d="M80.6 111.8v27.6h45.7c-1.8 11.9-13.8 34.8-45.7 34.8-27.5 0-50-22.8-50-50.9s22.5-50.9 50-50.9c15.7 0 26.1 6.7 32.1 12.4l21.9-21.1c-14.1-13.1-32.3-21.1-54-21.1C36.1 42.6 0 78.7 0 123.3s36.1 80.6 80.6 80.6c46.5 0 77.4-32.7 77.4-78.8 0-5.3-.6-9.3-1.3-13.4H80.6v.1zM253.4 111.8h-23v-23h-23v23h-23v23h23v23h23v-23h23"></path>
</svg>
```

I'm not sure what else to debug right now. How can I reference the svg somewhere outside of my main html code?

Comment: Do you have a `<base>` tag in your output that's interfering with URL resolution?

Comment: I do have a `<base>` tag in my `index.html` page. Would this break using svgs in the manner I want above?

Comment: Indeed, the purpose of a `<base>` tag is to change URL resolution and the xlink:href is a url fragment. There are workarounds in various questions and answers on this site about angular2 and svg.

Comment: This for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742805/angular-and-svg-filters/19753427#19753427

Comment: @RobertLongson This is it exactly. Crazy, I never would have thought of that! Thanks!