# SVG animation not working with angular routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I am using angularjs 1.2.25 and using svg animation on home page it is working fine on home page but when i switch from other menu tabs like from about us to home page again svg animation not working.I know the reason because it is not reloading the page when i switch but i don't know the solution.I would appreciate if anyone interested to address this problem.
Thank you

Comment: How are you triggering your animation?  Can you share that piece of your code?

Comment: <svg class="dxcLines web-folio" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1783 1996">
    <param 
     animationtime=".1"
     animateOnPageLoad="true"
     ></param>
   </svg>

Comment: Do you want javascript code?

Comment: anything relevant that may help us help you is welcomed

Comment: I assume you're having angular generate a base tag. Don't do that.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742805/angular-and-svg-filters

Comment: Actually i am just a beginner learning angularjs and svg and to be very honest i don't know what exactly should i give you..It'd be great if you ask for a specific element or piece of code.