# Blockly workspace background shows random image?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, svg-filters, blockly

I'm facing a weird bug which cause background of Blockly shows random image

The correct background should be like this:
[image: normal background]

But it shows random image (mostly favicon?) instead

[image: incorrect background]

It's really too weird to describe in words, please take a look at this [screen record](https://youtu.be/V8EP7ZxmnvQ)

I extract svg from Blockly (which I used in the video) that can reproduce the bug

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" class="blocklySvg" width="1209px" height="270px" style="display: block;">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="blocklyGridPattern5105292194395497" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="25" height="25" x="1202" y="219">
      <line stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" x1="11" y1="12.5" x2="14" y2="12.5"></line>
      <line stroke="#ccc" stroke-width="1" x1="12.5" y1="11" x2="12.5" y2="14"></line>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g class="blocklyWorkspace">
    <rect height="100%" width="100%" class="blocklyMainBackground" style="fill: url(#blocklyGridPattern5105292194395497);"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Is this a bug related to Chrome? or I misconfigured something?

---

Additional info about my environment

- Chrome 56 (seems only happens in Chrome)
- MacOS 10.12.4

Comment: The extracted code looks fine in Chrome. Usually this is a base-tag problem (common if you're using angular)

Comment: What does "base-tag problem" means?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742805/angular-and-svg-filters

Comment: Thanks for point that out. But I'm not using any `<base>` tag, and even if I use absolute URL the problem still exists :/

Comment: Then please post code that actually demonstrates the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some investigation, I think this is a bug of Chrome.

I already reported it to [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=710725), and they can finally reproduce this bug.

I answer my question just for record, in case someone have same issue.

Comment: My issue has been merged into [this one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=710443), seems they find the way to fix this