# SVG not showing on IOS when adding SVG filter

Tags: angular, svg, svg-filters

When adding a SVG filter to my SVG image it does not draw on IOS safari/chrome. Removing the `<defs>` will make the SVG draw. Some tip?

Tested on safari/chrome IOS 7-12

```
<svg class="w-100"
        viewBox="0 0 700 1100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <metadata></metadata>
        <defs>
          <filter id="filter-down" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <feFlood id="filter-down-feflood" result="flood" flood-color="#fff" />
            <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
          </filter>
          <filter id="filter-left" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <feFlood id="filter-left-feflood" result="flood" flood-color="#fff" />
            <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
          </filter>
          <filter id="filter-right" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <feFlood id="filter-right-feflood" result="flood" flood-color="#fff" />
            <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />

          </filter>

        </defs>
        <g class="cls-right">
            <image x="363" y="645" width="328" height="157" filter="url(#filter-right)"
              xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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" />
        </g>
        <g class="cls-down">
            <image  x="272" y="736" width="157" height="327" filter="url(#filter-down)"
              xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ0AAAFHCAQAAAAR/YagAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAACBjSFJNAAB6JgAAgIQAAPoAAACA6AAAdTAAAOpgAAA6mAAAF3CculE8AAAAAmJLR0QAAKqNIzIAAAAJcEhZcwAALiMAAC4jAXilP3YAAAAHdElNRQfjBgsMBiv3uRaPAAAVFklEQVR42u2ceXxU1b3AvzOTjYSwJCEQdghL2AQRSCiuYCuiVESrhbYKT0StgrY+22fdSqvWzxOrtah1fa+i1VJcK1pQtIqAAmrZF9lDCIgkgQTIOtM/ApiQOfec+8vM3MSe7/lv7j3nnvOde89+LzQ94hnFq4SOh53cSAo+rzPVPLiJjZSfVFfDIZ6jhdeZag7cxJaT2k6EUuaS43XGmjYJzGB3A3EhQgRZyDleZ6/p0olfUBhWXG14jzH4vc5kUySLBwk6iAsRYjHnEu91RpsaSTyp0VYbPmIkAa8z25Tw8yyHjdRV8hHDvM5u0yGVpykxEhciRBUfket1lpsGnXiSSmNxJx7bKbbO685jLrXVhu38lLZeZ95LsnlCJC5EiAPM+E+VFyCbD8XiQoQo5BYSvC6GF/Rkies6rn6oYTu3eF2M2DOQJVQbyNGdsY2feV2U2JLLe1opR3iC6ezUnreHn5HodYFixQje1gop4g+0A67hS+25+7iHHl4XKvr4GcIiA3GPknE8xrVsNnhwn6CT10WLLgmM4BOthnIepkOdWOP5wqBefI5kr4sXPeKYyFaqtBIepnu9yaUEzuRTbawy/vxtHWH4mcR2rYBSfk7XMNJHsVQb9xB/po3XxYw8cfyEddrCFzCdFEUKo1isjV/FM3T2uqiRJYmrDMRt4wbHVM5loVGD0cfr4kaOZCYZdDHyma5N6RzeNRiBvEBfr4scCXykcLlBx7aMqUbpjeSfdRYaVWEpfZv/XHIyv6VQ+5hV8mNlHVefOPrxlEGdt5zeXhe9cWTwMAe0BT3M1bRykWpvfq9Ns5plDPK6+HI68zCHtIVcwWXEuUy5I7M5ok35ffK8ViCju1HxlnOBKPVMHuKgNvWFjPRag3s68jDHtEX7nDHiK6TxewN57zO8Oc2r+GjFHMq0VflGvtOo62TyIEe18tZwYfORl8ocirUr+ZvJdV3H1cdHF/7XoMHYxQ+ax0T8QP5hsKq6mryI9Lw6MoVi7dV28OOm388bwTvagtTuHYkUfqYodkfVDRuY0sh7PMoMZ4G2EMeYz1kRvu40g4HeBqaS5LUgFTkGKw5lvEDPKFz7GnZpr73NeMwSUwL0YpnBHfdSmNm4yPATgw0/+UwitantS+7FMu2wvJJ5dI3a5sJkJmtzUMN+7qel17LqkscH2tWDKubSLaq5SGWyQYNxkDlkei3sBJcaPKo1PBeDjdQBLmC5Ni+HeTRq1YYrJrJWm9kCHqFfjPJzPku0+TnKI1FprFyQyEVsM6icb49py3Y2KwwarD96uYqRzFjHHechQgQp4caYr5Dmsl67aHmEx2nrVWs7jq+0I9USrqdNzDMYYBgbDf7UJ2nthbhLDVZV9/NTV/O/kcPPMD7T5u8Qixkc24y15gaDxmEXM0j1RFwtZ/KGNo8hFsVyOjSNu9irzdJ2bvb8pbihPG8wo7cwVhPx7bjdYMizgeubxARjD/6snXQN8T79o50RHx24XbuIXM2WJrSg0pkXDe68T+kT3Rm9ttxhsIC8iRFNaFbWTyf+os11BSuj2WlP5W6+0or7glFNbka2M/+n7edVs4TvRefyLbnHoHFY1og1rmjSh6cNtjd+waTIX3ooDxjcccv4rteOlPRlNvnaEqznishedqBBDynIWs7z2o8jyfzSYFJqJ+Mj1TcIMMBg43Q5S5vBy5ZJXMtB7eDxK8ZHZtQ9gH9oa4kgb5He5BqHhvhoxTXaPQNBihjf+IsN4Q2D7sjfojz/G0lSma6d7wmxi8sbd5nhvGKwi/Kl6PfFI0pLbmCHQYMxQ76pexjzDfbu/rWZiQNIYkaYr6mcGgq5h3T3iScw1mAdv5zXm9GjWl/eFP6lLV8Zd9HeXcKJjGOftjIt5s2TryM1R4azXtsA1nA3Hd1M1V5MgbYJP8B9pDW15WBXxDPE4JWESn5t/thOZLM2wUPc3azvuFr85LJKW9av+Y3ZXPcVBnVACXeT5XW5I8R5fGzQYMzSz3ePN7iFD/Drb8Ed9w1jDOQd4EGn0VJrLjXo7+xjVlPcL9QozuYLKrQlX6BaAmrDDO24IUgBs5rBgMs9g3mDUq289xnccINjgNuo1LaqB7nnW/rOqZ/WvKodANTwbsM773aD2bjPmSDpXTcbOvOy1kE5b3NG3Uj/YzD/+ykTv5WPal368YJBP++1E5/jasFtBq9urGRCs+7+mpLDi1oXQebRFx+MN3ir5gvGeV2mmNGF+Voj5cyhBbynWSuq4l8R3KrfHEjjFYo0TWYB3dG2KqsZ/R/2cVEfrZmlaTaLuBCNuOWRW+RoVqRzp+M7R0Vc5KzuJUY2oXX82NKeXzm8QlXEOLW6IK80w/nfSJLGHexR1HkO6ipYSnev8+45KTyiaESLGKdqAIp5mb1e59xzqviAGtVBv/L3Ft/S0aob/E5N5H9WtyOiWHVirDoxVp0Yq06MVSfGqhNj1Ymx6sRYdWKsOjFWnRirToxVJ8aqE2PVibHqxFh1Yqw6MVadGKtOjFUnxqoTY9WJserEWHVirDoxVp0Yq06MVSfGqhNj1Ymx6sRYdWKsOjFWnRirToxVJ8aqE2PVibHqxFh1Yqw6MVadGKtOjFUnxqoTY9WJserEWHVirDoxVp0Yq06MVSfGqhNj1Ymx6sRYdWKsOjFWnRirToxVJ8aqE2PVibHqxFh1Yqw6MVadGKtOjFUnxqoTY9WJserEWHVirDoxVp0Yq06MVSfGqhNj1Ymx6sRYdWKsOjFWnRirToxVJ8aqE2PVibHqxFh1Yqw6MVadGKtOjFUnxqoTY9WJserEWHVirDoxVp0Yq06MVSfGqhNj1Ymx6sRYdWKsOjFWnRirToxVJ8aqE2PVibHqxFh1Yqw6MVadGKtOjFUnxqoTY9WJserEWHVirDoxVp0Yq06MVSfGqhNj1Ymx6sRYdWKsOjFWnRirToxVJ8aqE2PVibHqxFh1Yqw6MVadGKtOjFUnxqoTY9WJserEWHVirDoxVp0Yq06MVSfGqhNj1Ymx6sRYdWKsOjFWnRirToxVJ8aqE2PVibHqxFh1Yqw6MXGNTiGRjiRSxh6vi2KAn4EMIZHdrG98fhujrjVXcAbdaEmAKorZzXu86bUdJblcSQ5pZBCgjCK+ZgVz2StPUKoulXFcwBi61vv1LM7mLf7ptaUGdGUClzD6lF9HM4S3eYWj0mRDYcNX/IIUZZxMZrJHEXM5l3htqh4+uvMElYrc7uM60pRxk7iC8rDxihgnUZfArRxQxAsRYhfDCXht7CSZ/M4hryH2MlWZW0d17ltYP2dwFRkOZ3RijuPx2JLHLx2PZ3E5PSUJu1cX5Db6OZ4RYDDjSI2hHjXDuR6f5pzzuEZ5LKSO5ldGqQ77ewJ5jCRek5lEptEl5prCMZBztee04Gx6hhXsJ1EtXqUujrZhj7Ugl5YGWc6lsxemGtCTFgZnZTE8bGlTyHavLpEeYSvPFE43agICdGoCI5VMw1osjsywilrQUR1JfddlKO66gdrHtZa+Do1+rBhk3AAEFb9WKmP41HdG+MRCVDpVnXXIpU9s/DjQl25G58UpGzV1ExPyUxJWRQJZYe+6KvYrpJ5KHtmx9RSGvmQanVfDsbC/t6Sv4rmsYoWfPWFV+OgW1ng5X1JllJ0kz++6LPoads2PsENxA7VR3Hd+yvwUK+6iFNqG+bWMVYpuS0OG0jf2vuowht6GZx5mRVgLSYobCEoI+CmkJuzBIJ3CRDvGSsXN3ZChXBh7XyfxcymdDM/dy76wd10r2oVVFySfoJ8tCnU+upMc5vddFBjWdh04J2wKsSBAf/JINDr3GOsVBjKUMfIJ+TmqaDH9DAv7yAZYSZlhAfrwvdgaO0kqUxxmfuqzm3Vhf09Rdm3K2ELQz5eKustP77DjhiBLOGCYqd5cF0tfdejMRONRdKHiruvEAEWMcvYR9LNOcdf56B/2cQuykBLDTMUzhIsjMInvlgym0tV4NLOeLWF/b69sZo6wlZCfvRSHPeynA+3D/B6iiNVUGGYrnTtoF0trAIzkR8YzhodYp2j4Oiq7V0dYQ9BPBdsUDUWAvoqK9n0KDDMWTx6TY9xY5DAt7J8eno/5RHGkO60VR4ooJuQnxFoOK04Zopg6WqGoHcIR4peMNhz3RoJUpvJ9F7lbxL/CHmmlbCSq2QngJ8jnyrprgGLq6EtWGY5kwUc7rue0qCs7cbXL+YGL8w+yUXGkv1LdXtZArbqVHFKcdBrdFUeWs8pFBsfwX2E7OpGnPz85ZZXOmVfZrDgyhIGKI8dbZD9BdnBQcVICpyue909420UGk7iSmdE0dpzTmc1IF0tKFfxFuRJ7urJ5y+dzqJ2vq+JLZYs5VOG+lE+UwsORznXcGuVuSifuYixJxufXsJRNil5tN+WcCeRTekIdfKLcRtCPPMWRdTzvqmBZzOKmqD22fk7jVi51FaeIp5Tjogn0Uhw5XL8X2Id/KNcpX1D+j30oIOi4xtkw3Bx2UqGxJHAWf3eZk0peU65bxPGWMt4iRtQ/+TGlhM+Va0rp/IZDLjMc4jmyI7xqEeBslrjOx3q+q6gVA/RnizLerFOrnWvZpzi1hPsVWfaTzQbXWT7Cwga7PxrHbWyiwnU+5irnVVL5LUXKeJNPPX0EixWnBllOa+Vc6XT2u850FWu4L0LDs5E8q9z94hSWM0SZZjvWUK2It4ZR4UyrLvMVPyJBcZlW/JUaQdbLeIkfN7LR6M/dfCi4dogiZihTTWYSx5Qx7w03hzeBEsXp5Syhg/JSY1glyn6IfGYzznDNqj4tOI2JzBNeN8SflF196McyZb1fEb6qyWG+w8UmOIxCb+CguBBlPM736Em64Sg3ifYM5lqHHoE+rGawMv0EpijjVfJx+JGKnx8qbVez0GGLTkvuFT20J0KQdTzAmbQinjgC+PGdrFt9+PDjJ0AcCXTjEp7lcCOuFaKESxxa+KEOnZxiptWdPv2moQ2yhk30DtvjD3AO57BVsYxYxiuNWsLxkUM3plLMVjaxhZVUUEo+AG3JIIkODCCb4XQmkRaNmsKqZDZLHdZWhnG+8lgpr9ftQtcVtZ+3uVExWErkalYph/zreIAshzZLR4CWtCSTbEZSShFBqjhKJZBKAgGSaE1L5eyZOdXM5xm+Vh7P5UrlAOAQb1CEYr4ontMoUN6u1dzruMdpokPcphEqmMcgR7UPObStq8lx7so/w1Fl5E1c5njhm9npuR6nsJjhjvkfw2Zl3FL+4HxDBxjKFw4Xf0ezh+MW8j0XJPvjfaTxvkPsD5XTIHV41qG1PMRszfjzRmXv0MsQJF/TjLXiHocuVo1yMFqP7/KZQxbWM8xRXgrXC8aT0Q6FjNXsBBjB1w63zEqzpfhk7lWO4EJUsViz2tSK6xzqSy/CW4zSdLizeccxhV8ZbQIGcjR99cc13YQEruITz4XVhmrmMlRT3kweckxjGaebiQOY7PhKSYibaaNJYSx/pdRzcTt5hP6anKZws+NA8giTXEza05knHLOUz2TtOkMmc9jr6f22jeu1SzzxXMl6h1SO8SLp5uIAcjUjxXcYqp3rjWMqO6jyQFuQo6wkV1tKHyMc532CrHe/rbc1MxVvR9WGchZqeuZQ+5bFkx6oK+VOOhisv2Wy0PGvLWSmcqbSMdm/O3YzKnjdqA7oyg+VM9DRCXM52+gdtZ4scLw9QsyTvsAwnLWOCVczx3BbTC6zWBMDaVW8ygzD7d8DtWtonzJMJg5gOrs1yf/RcJbXxwSeZlUUa75CPuAe443fQ/ibJr2dXCUXB3Cndrnw9/QyXtU/l7msZX+jJkYbhqPs4Z/crtwj0pA+vKZJs4xfGb1d5kA3ntEW9F3OcLGy2oGZfMYxKhstMEgVFRzlVa50MZfnpwsLNCnXMK/xLy74OU9bS1WwyMUmMB/JdOR8ftfo2u8QL3EtOaS56bKSyweaxiHEZoZG4j3yJC7WrrVWsJTpLv+S9gzmPGYwj7Uuxx37eI9HuZrv0MP1C8uTWO0wQq8NWznfRJzJ/g8/V3O/w3JiLTt4iSdcfz0kgd5kkU4mXehMW9JoQzpx1J3IDlDKXioooYQdFFJIAXsF3ynpyjQu0w7MCpnJfJPkTLfO3Mit9NCe9SxPscJ1kWrx05U0Mkgn4xR1cRxmNxUUUXR8sUfCSKZxlbZB28NDPCK+hoKfa6YEasMSLtben7Eng0tYYVQV3BqNyyfyiNEk5hEeJ9ODdyVUxNOe+ygzyHl59HaepjPbqBo/ykZXW6GjiY+r2WLYDN1Eq+hlpKvh/xdiG/M8ez/sG8Yx33CVrpwbo/3CfQbTlTvxTg2reICzPNOWx4N8bpjTA8x01TcUc5PDeuWp4QP+m/NMZ/YjRBrnciuLjPO4lptil7mprHYxkN/ALZxOZ8nMl0sS6cBw7mCTcd4qWePi3Z6IMJrlrhYNS3me80khKUofygqQSDoXModiF7mq4CNGxlYcxJOjWb84NRzjAJ/yEGdGJT+DuI9NFHPU1Z76P7mY9WlAYzbid+P73O3ym2HF7Gcva1jCeuUrRm7IIZdBnEYWWS6XXwq4gw/YLb90495hSGQ81zDWdbxjbKWQ7exiIzsocPXeD0BretKHnnSmF93pZPyq+jcs4EkWGH7DICrqAM7gKsYbjG/Ds56t7KGArynmCEcooho/JRwmeDxv1aSRRjU+svDThna0I41e9BN/gmYHi3lM8SpnTNUBXMsMOjWySxliPwfYRjlx7GQvVcenTyvpSTYV+BhCAt0a2cwUs4n/5znjb7XEgA48wH7lFzGbRqhkN7Ob3uSEj5acy8tNcJfTN+FlBpEShTfUIkCAHkyK8ZqraVjEleL6WHm3RJrh5DGaCw2/bBN9aniHxSzhs0gnHJ3bdwAX8x3yDD+BFj0KWM0y3mJ1NBKP3pOfyTQuoj0ZEdi0754SDrKTBfyF/dG6RHQrzQCj+T6X0oaEmH2uo5JKvuJNFvBejK4YJeJJIZPJvKVd+4xMqGEeE+lCSvT/qtg01clk0YEcRpGn+Ry0nA28ywY2sodCymNRqFj2cvz0pBs9yGYA2WRF5BMKh9jGNjaSz3Y2sz+WowQvOogBBpJNR/qQTiZtaEMW8cYToeVUcJAyiingANvZyraIzMG4xuu+dW+60oVBJNOTlsSR7DBGPUwNB9lNKVs5wK7odDnM8VpdfVqRo9ia5SPECuOvhMaEfwNEFTW3SgmmJgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
        </g>
        <g class="cls-left">
            <image x="10" y="646" width="328" height="157" filter="url(#filter-left)"
              xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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" />
        </g>
</svg>
```

Edit:
this was a angular problem. Fixed by editing the filter URL to include the angular route address before the filter name.

Before the fix:

```
.cls-left {
              filter: url(filter-left);
            }
```

After the fix ("remote" is the active angular route):

```
.cls-left {
              filter: url(/remote#filter-left);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The filter seems to be working perfectly as designed.  It is taking all the content of the SVG and making it white.  If you are then displaying that on a white background, you won't be able to see it.

But if you make the background black, you will see that it is indeed working.

```css
svg {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<svg class="w-100"
        viewBox="0 0 700 1100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <metadata></metadata>
        <defs>
          <filter id="filter-down" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <feFlood id="filter-down-feflood" result="flood" flood-color="#fff" />
            <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
          </filter>
          <filter id="filter-left" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <feFlood id="filter-left-feflood" result="flood" flood-color="#fff" />
            <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
          </filter>
          <filter id="filter-right" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <feFlood id="filter-right-feflood" result="flood" flood-color="#fff" />
            <feComposite result="composite" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
          </filter>

        </defs>
        <g class="cls-right">
            <image x="363" y="645" width="328" height="157" filter="url(#filter-right)"
              xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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" />
        </g>
        <g class="cls-down">
            <image  x="272" y="736" width="157" height="327" filter="url(#filter-down)"
              xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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" />
        </g>
        <g class="cls-left">
            <image x="10" y="646" width="328" height="157" filter="url(#filter-left)"
              xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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" />
        </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I use a background color on a background deeper down. When I use the SVG standalone, it seems to work. But I still does not draw in my angular8+bootstrap4 webapp. Maybe there are some class conflicts.

Comment: @Robert Longson, can you explain?

Comment: @Robert Longson. Do you have some example on how to do that or some article explaining this?

Comment: Angular routing uses `<base>` tags by default(?). This interferes with the URL resolution in things like `filter="url(#filter-left)"`. The `#filter-left` part is a URL fragment, and will be resolved relative to whatever is in your base element.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742805/angular-and-svg-filters